# How to convert string to time in Python Only H and M

Tags: python, time

I would convert a string, to time format, without seconds, any help?

```
import datetime

time = '23:45'
conv=datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M')
print(conv)
```

The result is:

```
1900-01-01 23:45:00
```

I would only have `23:45`

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what you *think* the `strptime` function *should* return, given [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) quite explicitly mentions that it returns `datetime`?

Comment: Can you also provide a bit more information about how your expected output differs from what you already have in `time`?

Comment: The string in text format is extracted from html code by web scraping, then I want to write the data in an excel table, but they are transcribed in text format and not numeric, so I can't add the total amount of hours..

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
from datetime import *

time = datetime.strptime("03/02/21 16:30", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
print("Time = {:d}:{:02d}".format(time.hour, time.minute))
```